# Stripping http:// and subpage / path using excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Ive got a list of urls like this

```
http://example.com
http://www.somesite.com/mypage
anothersite.com/somepage
http://example.com/anotherpage
www.yetanothersite.com
```

As you can see theres a mixture of sites with / without `http://`, with / without subpages, with / without `www.`

What im trying to do is sanitise the list so it reads like this (below) ie. removing the `http://`, removing the subpages, but leaving the `www.` if present.

```
example.com
www.somesite.com
anothersite.com
example.com
www.yetanothersite.com
```

Whats the best way to do this in Google Spreadsheets  ? Idealy something like php's `parse_url()` function would be great. Ive been experimenting using `=MID(A1, FIND("//", A1)+2, FIND("/",A1,10)-8)` but the problem with this is it strips away the `www.`, is there a better way to do this, preferably using custom functions rather than macros so that it would work in both excel and Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a formula. The same formula will work for both Google Sheets and Excel.

```
=MID(A2,IFERROR(SEARCH("//",A2)+2,1),IFERROR(SEARCH("/",A2,IFERROR(SEARCH("//",A2)+2,1))-IFERROR(SEARCH("//",A2)+2,1),LEN(A2)))
```

It's a bit long and ugly but not too hard to understand if you break it down

```
=MID(A2, 'Take a slice from the middle of the string in cell A2
  IFERROR( 'Return the value found in the next statement, unless its an error
    SEARCH("//",A2)+2 'Search the string for // and take the position after it
    ,1 'otherwise start from the start of the string if its not found
  )
, IFERROR(
  SEARCH("/",A2, 'Search for / in the string
    IFERROR(SEARCH("//",A2)+2,1) 'Start after the // if it was found
  )
  -IFERROR(
    SEARCH("//",A2)+2,1) 'Since the second parameter of mid is a length
                         'not a position, subtract the location of //
                         'again if it was found
    , LEN(A2) 'Otherwise take all of the remaining string
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

VBA; Chop off all before `//` then read until the next `/`

```
Function getDomain(url As String) As String
    Dim pos As Long

    pos = InStr(url, "//")
    If (pos > 0) Then
        url = Mid$(url, 2 + pos)
    End If

    pos = InStr(url, "/")
    If (pos > 0) Then
        url = Left$(url, pos - 1)
    End If

    getDomain = url
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This formula will do it:

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"http://",""),FIND("/",SUBSTITUTE(A1&"/","http://",""))-1)
```

Using your examples:

1. `http://example.com`

`SUBSTITUTE(A1,"http://","")` =
 **example.com**

`FIND("/",SUBSTITUTE(A1&"/","http://",""))-1` =
`FIND("/","example.com/")-1` =
 **11**

`LEFT("example.com",11)` =
 **example.com**

---

2. `http://www.somesite.com/mypage`

`SUBSTITUTE(A1,"http://","")` =
 **www.somesite.com/mypage**

`FIND("/",SUBSTITUTE(A1&"/","http://",""))-1` =
`FIND("/","www.somesite.com/mypage/")-1` =
 **16**

`LEFT("www.somesite.com/mypage",16)` =
 **www.somesite.com**

---

3. `anothersite.com/somepage`

`SUBSTITUTE(A1,"http://","")` =
 **anothersite.com/somepage**

`FIND("/",SUBSTITUTE(A1&"/","http://",""))-1` =
`FIND("/","anothersite.com/somepage/")-1` =
 **15**

`LEFT("anothersite.com/somepage",15)` =
 **anothersite.com**

---

4. `http://example.com/anotherpage`

`SUBSTITUTE(A1,"http://","")` =
 **example.com/anotherpage**

`FIND("/",SUBSTITUTE(A1&"/","http://",""))-1` =
`FIND("/","example.com/anotherpage/")-1` =
 **11**

`LEFT("example.com/anotherpage",11)` =
 **example.com**

---

5. `www.yetanothersite.com`

`SUBSTITUTE(A1,"http://","")` =
 **www.yetanothersite.com**

`FIND("/",SUBSTITUTE(A1&"/","http://",""))-1` =
`FIND("/","www.yetanothersite.com/")-1` =
 **22**

`LEFT("www.yetanothersite.com",22)` =
 **www.yetanothersite.com**